# Is integration by parts true in arbitrary open sets?

Tags: integration, analysis, variational-analysis

I am learning variational analysis from "Variational Analysis in Sobolev and BV Spaces - Applications to Pdes and Optimization" (https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611973488) and i am not sure if i have found an error or there is something i am missing. In the proof of proposition 2.2.6 (pag. 24), where it is prooved that weak derivative, in the sense of distributions, coincides with classical derivative whenever classical derivative exists, the proof uses the integration by parts formula, a result that needs the open set $\Omega$ (which is the set where the functions we are working with are defined) to be bounded and have piecewise smooth boundary (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Theorem), but the book does not say anything about this, just uses the formula as if it es valid for an arbitrary open set $\Omega$. This same "error" (using integration by parts formula for arbitrary open $\Omega$) is repeated is pag.32, where he obtains the weak formulation for the Neumann boundary problem. So, i am wondering if is this an error and i should acept this results only in case $\Omega$ is bounded and have piecewise smooth boundary, or there is some way to overcome this dificult and apply integration by parts for an arbitrary open $\Omega$.

Thanks.

Comment: Conventionally we do this when the integrand vanishes outside a compact set contained in $\Omega$.  An additional advantage to this is that the boundary terms of the integration by parts are zero.  So, in that book, what did they do with the boundary terms?  If the boundary is not a rectifiable curve??

Comment: In the wikipedia article, where it finally gets down to mentioning the stuff you are talking about (why did you link to a point so far away from what you were referencing?), note the line "The regularity requirements of the theorem can be relaxed." Exactly how they can be relaxed so as to fit this usage, I cannot say, as I have no desire to spend money to research what this usage is for you.

Comment: @GEdgar in the book the functions under consideration have compact support inside $\Omega$, so, if i undestood what you said, is there any proof of integration by parts formula for functions with compact support inside $\Omega$ for arbitrary $\Omega$? Maybe, using the fact that it vanishes on a compact, is it possible to replace $\Omega$ with a different open set $\Omega'$ with piecewise smooth boundary?

Comment: @GEdgar There is no comment in the book about regularity on the boundary, even when they use arbitrary open sets, that is why i was not fully understanding.

Comment: If the test function vanishes outside a compact set inside $\Omega$, then the integrand (and all its derivatives) vanishes on a neighborhood of the boundary of $\Omega$.  That is the best conceivable regularity on the boundary.  You can replace $\Omega$ with any larger open set $\Omega'$, making no change on the inttegrals.